# Sum of Users balance with updated version between two days

Tags: python, pandas

I have users latest balance every day and I can see in the lates_balance column below

```
+----+------+------------+----------------+--+
|    | user | date        | latest_balance |  |
|  0 | A    | 2019-07-26 | 705.0          |  |
|  1 | A    | 2019-07-29 | 990.0          |  |
|  2 | A    | 2019-07-30 | 5.0            |  |
|  3 | A    | 2019-07-31 | 25.0           |  |
|  4 | A    | 2019-08-01 | 155.0          |  |
|  5 | A    | 2019-08-02 | 405.0          |  |
|  6 | A    | 2019-08-03 | 525.0          |  |
|  7 | A    | 2019-08-05 | 1000.0         |  |
|  8 | A    | 2019-08-06 | 825.0          |  |
|  9 | B    | 2019-08-07 | 230.0          |  |
| 10 | A    | 2019-08-07 | 965.0          |  |
| 11 | B    | 2019-08-08 | 224.0          |  |
| 12 | A    | 2019-08-08 | 80.0           |  |
| 13 | A    | 2019-08-09 | 380.0          |  |
| 14 | B    | 2019-08-10 | 4.0            |  |
| 15 | B    | 2019-08-11 | 114.0          |  |
| 16 | A    | 2019-08-12 | 725.0          |  |
| 17 | B    | 2019-08-12 | 234.0          |  |
| 18 | A    | 2019-08-13 | 815.0          |  |
| 19 | B    | 2019-08-13 | 243.0          |  |
| 20 | B    | 2019-08-15 | 13.0           |  |
| 21 | A    | 2019-08-16 | 75.0           |  |
| 22 | B    | 2019-08-16 | 53.0           |  |
| 23 | A    | 2019-08-17 | 890.0          |  |
| 24 | B    | 2019-08-17 | 36.0           |  |
| 25 | A    | 2019-08-19 | 100.0          |  |
| 26 | A    | 2019-08-20 | 115.0          |  |
| 27 | A    | 2019-08-21 | 150.0          |  |
+----+------+------------+----------------+--+
```

we can see if the user is not active in someday we cannot see the users balance and we cannot make with a total daily sum.

I need to calculate the total balance of each user even they do not have any transaction with their last balance.

my idea was to use python dictionary and `dict.update()` them. 
so if the user has a transaction and new balance add if not add the previous transaction for all day.

my code is:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
date_upd =[]
total = {}
date_t ={} 
start_date = min(df['date'])
end_date = max(df['date'])

delta = timedelta(days=1)


while start_date <= end_date:

    for i,k in enumerate(df['date']):
        if(k == start_date):
            #print(k)
            total.update({df['user'][i]:df['latest_balance'][i]})

        else:



            total.update({df['user'][i]:df['latest_balance'][i]})
            pass

        date_upd.append(sum(total.values()))

        start_date += delta

        #date_t.update(total)
```

and gives me this result

```
+----------+
|   705.0, |
|   990.0, |
|     5.0, |
|    25.0, |
|   155.0, |
|   405.0, |
|   525.0, |
|  1000.0, |
|   825.0, |
|  1055.0, |
|  1195.0, |
|  1189.0, |
|   304.0, |
|   604.0, |
|   384.0, |
|   494.0, |
|   839.0, |
|   959.0, |
|  1049.0, |
|  1058.0, |
|   828.0, |
|    88.0, |
|   128.0, |
|   943.0, |
|   926.0, |
|   136.0, |
|   151.0, |
|    186.0 |
+----------+
```

which is extra a few results because of not looping each day.

should be

```
705.0,
 990.0,
 5.0,
 25.0,
 155.0,
 405.0,
 525.0,
 1000.0,
 825.0,
      ,
 1195.0,
      ,
 304.0,
 604.0,
 384.0,
 494.0,
 839.0,
 959.0,
      ,
 1058.0,
 828.0,
      ,
 128.0,
      ,
 926.0,
 136.0,
 151.0,
 186.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question 100% but something like this?

`df.pivot_table(columns='user', index='date', values='latest_balance').ffill().sum(axis=1)`

Comment: omg, are you serious! how I could not think, this is smart thank you